# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet.Cells[x,y].Style?

Tags: c#, automation, export-to-excel, excel-interop

I found some code which uses Style property of `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet.Cells[x,y]` but it is treated as an object in my Visual Studo code editor:

```
Workbook wb = new Application.Workbooks.Add(XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);
Worksheet ws = wb.Sheets[1];
ws.Cells[x,y] is simply treated as an object so how can I use its Style property?
```

I'm using Microsoft Excel 15.0 Objects Library (goes with Microsoft Office 2013). Does that matter?

Could you please explain this to me? Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps that code is using `dynamic`.

Comment: Sound interesting, please give me some example (or link) on that 'dynamic', thanks.

Comment: [Google C# 4 dynamic](http://www.google.com/search?q=C%23+4+dynamic)

Comment: @CodesInChaos thanks, your link reminds me to google more, but sometimes I want to ask right in here, lazy for a while simply because I don't really want to dig into something new at the moment. There are still many features of C# 3.5 I haven't experienced yet. Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you have to cast the object as a `Range`.

The Range interface/object contains all the style and value information for the cell or range that you are specifying.

some examples:

```
((Excel.Range)ws.Cells[r, c]).NumberFormat = format;
((Excel.Range)ws.Cells[r, c]).Value2 = cellVal;
((Excel.Range)ws.Cells[r, c]).Interior.Color = ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.Red);
((Excel.Range)ws.Cells[r, c]).Style.Name = "Normal"
```

etc etc and so on.

Have a link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.Style

Comment: Or, if you aren't changing the location, you can assign the result to a Range object first. `Range neededRange = ws.Cells[r,c];` Then use the Range methods. It makes the code read a little cleaner and it's how I write my Excel reports.

Comment: True, I took the examples from an interface where r, c, and some other parameter (depending on the function) get passed in from another engine.  So each of those lines is in a different function :-).  Casting to range and assigning it to its own Range variable is great if you are going to re-use the same range for several different things as once before discarding or re-assigning it.

Comment: Thanks, I tried looking for a type of Cell in Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel namespace but it doesn't exist. Maybe Range is not only for a group of cells but also a particular cell. But do you know why some code on internet that Style can be accessed directly on Cell[x,y] as if it's type of Range without casting first? Thanks for help.

Comment: CodesInChaos called it, its very likely a "dynamic" variable.  That's the only reason I can think of that they wouldn't need to cast back to a range specifically before accessing things that are very obviously Range properties.

Comment: Thanks, it is exactly dynamic style used only in Visual 2010 or above, but I'm testing the code in Visual 2008 although my laptop has both Visual 2010 Ultimate and Visual 2012 installed.

Answer (score 0):

You might also like to check out [stackoverflow.com/questions/15366340/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15366340/data-formatted-in-datagrid-is-exported-to-excel-in-unformatted-manner/15953667#15953667) which includes cell formatting while exporting to excel.